# Configuring tomcat for internal log with log4j!

Tags: apache, log4j, tomcat6

I am using `apache-tomcat-6.0.18` and want to configure log4j for tomcat internal logging.

I gone through the tomcat site [Logging in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j). But i didn't understood the `STEP 3,4,5`.

What is the `extras components`? How can these be helpful for Logging?

If someone can guide me Step By Step will really help !!!

Please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to build Tomcat from source then get the tomcat-juli.jar and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar from this location:
http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.32/bin/extras/

and replace the .jar files as per the instructions.

$CATALINA_HOME is where your Tomcat 6.0 is installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried as it mentioned in the instruction. But i am gettign error like this `log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CATALINA.layoutlog4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [CATALINA]. log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [LOCALHOST].`  and tomcat is not going ahead for further processing

Answer (score 0):

`@Thanks DaveRead`, I got my problem resolved, I just made some changes in log4j.properties file and its working. Here is entry.

`....`
`....`

`#Roll-over the log once per day`
`log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.CATALINA.append=true`

`log4j.appender.LOCALHOST=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.file=${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.log
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.encoding=UTF-8`
`#Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.append=true`
`...`
`...`